# Cordova run ubuntu not work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cordova

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I can not run application using the "cordova run ubuntu", gives the following error :

```
paulo@paulo-notebook:~/hello$ sudo cordova run ubuntu
ReferenceError: name is not defined
    at Object.ConfigParser.setDescription (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/ConfigParser.js:70:45)
    at Object.module.exports.update_from_config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/ubuntu_parser.js:74:21)
    at Object.module.exports.update_project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/ubuntu_parser.js:156:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/prepare.js:113:31
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

And earlier also gives the following error when doing "cordova platform add ubuntu"

```
paulo@paulo-notebook:~/hello$ cordova platform add ubuntu
Downloading cordova library for ubuntu...
Download complete
Checking ubuntu requirements...
Running "dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' cmake debhelper libx11-dev libicu-dev pkg-config qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^i'" (output to follow)

Creating ubuntu project...
Shelljs module was not found, running 'npm install'.....
ReferenceError: name is not defined
    at Object.ConfigParser.setDescription (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/ConfigParser.js:70:45)
    at Object.module.exports.update_from_config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/ubuntu_parser.js:74:21)
    at Object.module.exports.update_project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/ubuntu_parser.js:156:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/prepare.js:113:31
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Does anyone know what can be ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a JavaScript bug of Cordova that you can fix by following next steps

```
$ sudo vim /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/ConfigParser.js
```

Go to line 69. Here you'll find this:

```
setDescription: function() {
    this.doc.find('description').text = name;
    var el = findOrCreate(this.doc, 'description');
},
```

The problem is in line 70 caused by the variable called `name`: it is undefined.
To fix this bug you need to add `name` as an input parameter of the `setDescription` function, like this:

```
setDescription: function(name) {
    this.doc.find('description').text = name;
    var el = findOrCreate(this.doc, 'description');
},
```

Save your changes. Since the Ubuntu platform has been added - I assume incorrectly - you should go into the platforms directory of your Cordova project and delete the ubuntu directory

```
$ cd ~/hello/platforms
$ rm -r ubuntu
```

Now you need to rerun:

```
$ cordova platform add ubuntu
```

Finally it should run without errors.

I've opened an issue about it to Apache Software Fundation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6643

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `cordova run "supported platforms" /cordova add "supported platforms"` . And **ubunto** is not a supported platform.

Have a look at this page: [Apache Cordova Documentation - The Command-line Interface](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html)

Supported platforms are:

- iOS
- Android
- BlackBerry
- Windows Phone 8

For example: cordova add android / cordova run wp8 , ....

Comment: I used this command on ubuntu 10.13 and it worked. I tried the command cordova add "supported platform" and did not work.

paulo@paulo-notebook:~/hello$ cordova add ubuntu
Cordova does not know add; try help for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface for version 3.4.

Comment: paulo@paulo-notebook:~/hello$ cordova platforms
Installed platforms: ubuntu 3.4.0-dev
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, firefoxos

Comment: You may use `cordova add "supportedPlatform"` and replce supportedPlatform with one one really supported platforms like andoid.

Comment: Android Platform ==> `cordova add android`, iOS platform ==> `cordova add ios`, Windows Phone 8 platform ==> `cordova add wp8`, ....

Comment: Not work ...

paulo@paulo-notebook:~/hello$ cordova add android
Cordova does not know add; try help for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: This is command: cordova platform add "platform supported", and i used ubuntu with ubuntu-sdk ... but on ubuntu 13.10 and not ubuntu 14.04